# referencing fields created in repeater from postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've built a form using a repeater and now I want to reference the fields on my click event.

I can get to them from inside an item loop

```
For Each item In formRepeater.Items
    myField = item.FindControl(dr("controlName"))
Next
```

but how can I get to it from outside of a loop?

```
formRepeater.items... what next?
```

**EDIT**

trying to use the indexes don't seem to line up right? `items(0)` worked for the first 2 records.

I think I may actually want to loop through the repeater instead of the datatable anyway, how can I access the values of the datasource? in the dataBound sub I can say

```
dim drv as dataRowView = e.Item.DataItem

x = drv("columnName").toString()
```

but that doesn't seem to work in the click handler.

I've tried various versions of the below but keep getting errors

```
Dim drv As DataRowView
For Each item In formRepeater.Items
    drv = item.dataItem
    theText = drv("fieldType").ToString()  'ERROR drv not sent to an instance of an object
    tempText = item.FindControl(drv("controlName"))
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried: `myField = DirectCast(formRepeater.Items(index).FindControl("controlName"), FieldType)` as `.Items` is a collection and then your control could be inside it...

Comment: @Zaggler please see my edit. thank you for the help